# Does rails support queries which order by a value in a foreign key?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, querying

Suppose I have two models

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
end

class B < ApplicationRecord
end
```

where A has a foreignkey pointing to B. Suppose also that B has an additional unique identifier for it's ordering used with rails_sortable. Is there a way to query all of the objects in A by ordering the by this unique identifier in B?

Comment: You should select A and join B then order by B.identifier

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your question.

```
as_objs = A.joins('INNER JOIN bs on as.key_used_as_foreign_key_from_bs = bs.key_used_as_foreign_key_to_as').order('bs.additional_unique_identifier_key')
```